# При запуске Visual Studio 2010 shell возникает ошибка "Invalid license data. Reinstall is required."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8

При запуске *Visual Studio 2010 shell* возникает ошибка:

> Invalid license data. Reinstall is required."

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что именно непонятно автору вопроса... Вам же русским по белому говорят, что хреновые лицензионные данные и требуется переустановка. Переставить пробовали? С лицензией что?

Comment: Перестанавливать пробывал а лицензия бесплатная